# How Can Insert Multi Rows in a table using array

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I need to add multirows at the same time in my sql server Table using this code

```
declare @idproduct int
declare @idfile int

set @idproduct = (select id from Products where name = 'DR-8416')
set @idfile = (select id from Files where filename like '%8416%')

insert into ProductsFiles(idproducts, idfile) values (@idproduct, @idfile)
```

that @idfile is an array with many values;
when I try to add I recied this error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

How Can I solve this Problem ?

Comment: What you have there doesn't make sense as it stands. What are you expecting to `INSERT` here? A cartesian product of every `id` from `Files` and `Products` (that meet the requisite of the `WHERE`)?

Comment: Use While loop to fetch each record and insert to your target table

Comment: @Sreenu131 no, don't use a `WHILE` loop, that is awfully slow. SQL Server excels as Set Based methods, not iterative ones. I suggest against using that methodology Farshad Razaghi.

Comment: @Larnu I have some products that has many files; an a table that connect them together. some files are same for some products

Comment: So what links `Files` and `Products`? Don't forget, we can't see your data, and we don't have any samples or expected results. Best I can suggest at the moment is you want `INSERT INTO...SELECT` syntax.

Comment: Products.id and Files.id connect the tables, I want to store this id's in ProductsFiles Table @Larnu

Comment: That doesn't make sense, It seems you're stating that `Products.id` and `Files.id` should have the same value? That seems wrong; they are 2 different keys, so that is very unlikely (but if it is, then they should be one table, not 2). I've made my guess anyway; without further detail there's little more I can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can guess is what you are after is:

```
INSERT INTO ProductsFiles (idproducts,
                           idfile)
SELECT P.id,
       F.id
FROM Products AS P
     CROSS JOIN Files AS F
WHERE P.[name] = 'DR-8416'
  AND F.[filename] LIKE '%8416%';
```

Note I have used as `CROSS JOIN`, as your question suggests there is no relationship between `Products` and `Files`. If there is change the `CROSS JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` and add the relevant `ON` clause. If you don't know about `JOIN` syntax I suggest looking it up, and learning it. `JOIN` syntax is one of the fundamentals for SQL and you will not get far without learning it. You will learn far more by taking the time to read up about it than me giving you an answer and trying to explain the basics.